# subquery to retrieve a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My `Sales.Customer` table includes the following columns:

- CustomerID (integer)
- FirstName (nvarchar(50))
- LastName (nvarchar(50))

My `Sales.SalesOrder` table includes the following columns:

- SalesOrderNumber (integer)
- OrderDate (date)
- CustomerID (integer)
- Amount (money)

Some customers have placed multiple orders over a period of years. I've written the following query to retrieve the last date on which each customer placed an order:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName,
            -- correlated subquery goes here
               AS LastOrderDate
FROM Sales.Customer AS c;
```

Why does my subquery not complete my actual query? Am I missing something or should it be something different?

```
(SELECT MAX(o.OrderDate)
    FROM Sales.SalesOrder AS o
    WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
```

I considered whether I might be over-complicating my solution so maybe this should work instead?

```
  (SELECT MAX(c.OrderDate)
    FROM Sales.Customer AS c)
```

Comment: Which is it - `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: apologies, it's sql-server, trans-sql to be exact, I just thought putting in the tag of mysql would draw more users to see it. I'll remove it immediately because it certainly will affect reputation.

Comment: OK. I don't understand what you mean by "Why does my subquery not complete my actual query? " -- your first subquery should work (not your second).

Comment: Please post the exact query you need help with; along with some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: should work.. you should join the 2 tables though and use `group by`

Comment: @Blogbeard, you are correct, i seem to have miss-written it when writing the query but spelt it correctly when typing it here.How odd. Thank you for your confidence and help however, I could certainly do with having you around, I may post another question shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to rewrite it as a CTE like this.

```
;WITH LastOrderDate AS
(
    SELECT CustomerID,MAX(OrderDate) AS LastOrderDate
    FROM Sales.SalesOrder
    GROUP BY CustomerID

)
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, LastOrderDate
               AS LastOrderDate
FROM Sales.Customer AS c
LEFT JOIN LastOrderDate l
ON c.CustomerID = l.CustomerID;
```